# name 'ValidationError' is not defined in django form

Tags: django

I'm trying to restrict a user if they enter an e-mail that already exists during registration. This is the error i get

```
Exception Value:    
name 'ValidationError' is not defined
```

User Form

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser 

    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
            email = forms.EmailField()
        
        
            def clean(self):
                email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
                if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
                    return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Django 3, you need to import it using: `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`.

For Django 2 the docs have it as: `forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")`.

See the Django 3 docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).
See the Django 2 docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).